# wordpress website gets overloaded - too many apache process

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, wordpress

My website gets overloaded at random times. I noticed too many apache processes and as a result it freezes. We don't have such traffic to cause this. At that moment all I can do is restart the server.

Trying to debug the issue I get this from mod_status. At some point i see too many processes without PID, in 'Open slot with no current process' state, around 75:

```
Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  Protocol    VHost   Request
0-0 -   0/0/18  .   12.08   314 0   0.0 0.00    0.12    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
1-0 -   0/0/16  .   6.63    286 0   0.0 0.00    0.08    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
2-0 20533   0/34/34 _   45.02   7   0   0.0 0.29    0.29    213.140.194.20  http/1.1    any.com:80  GET /server-status/?refresh=5 HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/14  .   17.98   320 0   0.0 0.00    0.07    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
4-0 -   0/0/17  .   5.40    307 0   0.0 0.00    0.06    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
5-0 -   0/0/17  .   6.91    306 0   0.0 0.00    0.06    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
6-0 -   0/0/18  .   17.41   319 0   0.0 0.00    0.11    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
7-0 -   0/0/21  .   13.20   283 0   0.0 0.00    0.09    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
8-0 -   0/0/16  .   6.74    281 0   0.0 0.00    0.07    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
9-0 -   0/0/17  .   7.34    308 0   0.0 0.00    0.08    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
10-0    -   0/0/9   .   1.41    296 0   0.0 0.00    0.03    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
11-0    -   0/0/2   .   0.00    316 0   0.0 0.00    0.00    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
12-0    -   0/0/2   .   0.00    318 0   0.0 0.00    0.00    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
13-0    -   0/0/6   .   0.69    274 0   0.0 0.00    0.41    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
14-0    -   0/0/4   .   1.12    292 0   0.0 0.00    0.02    ::1 http/1.1    any.com:80  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

What do all these mean? Can they be the cause of the overload?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins and see if the crash still occurs?

Comment: this is a live website and disabling all plugins is not an option. Probably is some plugin, but how to know?

Comment: Can you disable one plugin at a time? That would be easiest and have the minimal impact on your setup. If you've got the time, you could also clone your website with one of many wordpress plugins and move it to an offline server and do your testing there.

Comment: do all those processes mean something?